# How to unlock an optimistically locking before commiting (in Hibernate)?

Tags: java, hibernate

In Hibernate how to unlock an object, that has been optimistically locked?

Look at these code excerpts (all this happens in the same transaction!):

```
session.lock(item, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
...
session.delete(item);
...
transaction.commit();
```

In the beginning the object is marked as to be optimistically locked.
But later in the transaction it is decided to delete it instead of updating it.
This results in the error

> ```
> org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by
> another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)
> ```

Therefore my question: How can I unlock it before removing? In a way like this:

```
session.lock(item, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
...
if (hasToBeDeleted) {
  [here: do unlock - how?]
  session.delete(item);
} else {
  session.update(item);
}
...
transaction.commit();
```

P.S.: Why am I calling `session.lock` in all cases? The reason is, that  `session.lock` happens in a central class that doesn't know the variable `hasToBeDeleted`. And in most of the cases the lock makes sense when only updates take place.

Comment: you can catch the exception, load the new entity and delete it

Comment: @office.aizaz 1. The exception is only thrown on commit. 2. The aim is, that no exception is thrown.

Comment: The point of hibernate throwing an exception is to let the application know that the entity that was locked has been updated/deleted by another part of application and the entity you currently hold is stale. If you go ahead with your changes, the change made by other part of application will be lost. Is that the behaviour are you looking for?

Comment: @office.aizaz No, this is not the point. StaleState makes sense, when another thread or user updates the entity. In this case, as described above, this happens in the same thread and transaction! The reason is, that the optimistic lock happens on commit (by incrementing the version) - although it had been already defined in the beginning. As at this point the record is already deleted, the locking fails. Now one can say: why are you locking at all? The reason is, that this lock definition happens in a central class and in most of the cases the lock makes sense as only updates take place.